# how to solve Value Error in tensorflow.keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp

I have some project about korean NLP. my project's purpose is classfiying sentence by three category(none, offensive, hate). input data was padded by 45 length. so i created simple DL model and input preprocessed data to model. i want to create DL model to classify cursed_sentence

so i'm using keras of tensorflow-cpu(version:2.5.0 / python version = 3.7.9). i  was faced some problem with using keras. i created very simple LSTM model by using Keras. i created embedding layer. input_dim of embedding layer is vocab_size + 1 (vocab_size is 24844) and created LSTM layers and final layers that used softmax for activation function

but i checked occuring 'ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 1) are incompatible.' i submit some code and error message. i can't understand why this error occurs and which part of errors occured

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

METRICS = [
    keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
    keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
    keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
    keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'),
    keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
    keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
    keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall'),
    keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')
]

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(len(tk.word_index)+1, 100, input_length=45))
model.add(layers.LSTM(100))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor = 'val_auc',
    verbose = 1,
    patience = 10,
    mode = 'max',
    restore_best_weights=True)

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=METRICS)

baseline_history = model.fit(train_data, train_label, batch_size = 8192, epochs = 100, callbacks = [early_stopping], validation_split = 0.2, class_weight = class_weight)
```

below content is summary that created simple model

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 45, 100)           2484500
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 100)               80400
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 3)                 303
=================================================================
Total params: 2,565,203
Trainable params: 2,565,203
Non-trainable params: 0
```

and below content is occured error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "learning.py", line 85, in <module>
    baseline_history = model.fit(train_data, train_label, batch_size = 8192, epochs = 100, callbacks = [early_stopping], validation_split = 0.2, class_weight = class_weight)
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1183, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 889, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 933, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 764, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3050, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3444, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py", line 3289, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 999, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py", line 672, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 986, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:800 train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:460 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:86 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:1005 update_state  **
        sample_weight=sample_weight)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:366 update_confusion_matrix_variables
        y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
    C:\Users\pllab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 3) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

i tried to solve this problem but i can't find appropriate answers. sorry for my english and please give me some advice for this error.

Comment: Can you please show `train_data.shape` and `train_label.shape` ?

Comment: thanks for your helping! my train_data.shape is (190053, 45) and train_label.shape is (190053, ) train_data is padded by 45 length and train_label's values is 0,1,2(0 is none, 1 is offensive, 2 is hate)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really into ML, but try changing

> model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

to

> model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))

and see if the error still occured

Edit:
or check the elements of train_label. I think it was supposed to have 3 label values (because your last layer has 3 outputs)

Comment: i tried you suggested one. so i checked no more occured same error. thanks. but i have some new errors. 

 tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  indices[3845,21] = 45098 is not in [0, 24845)
         [[node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup (defined at learning.py:86) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3203]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup:

i will find some way to handle it... thanks!

Comment: This is wrong, a softmax shouldnt have 1 neuron as output.

Comment: If you have a single layer as output then the activation function should be sigmoid, for softmax you can expect as many neurons as labels...

Comment: Yes, after remembering a little, your softmax layer was correct (because you wanted to classify 3 categories). So, check your train_label, I think it supposed to have 3 values. @CeliusStingher can you confirm if this is correct?

Comment: We don't really know how many categories OPs data has, nor the size of the data, that's why I asked them to tell us the shape and number of labels.